# Why I can use index on "select count(*) from table_name" but cannot work on "select * from table_name" ? Is there any difference?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table like this:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+--------------------------------------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default                              | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+--------------------------------------+-------+
| id           | varchar(36)  | NO   | PRI | NULL                                 |       |
| provider_id  | varchar(36)  | YES  | MUL | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |       |
| to_provider  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                                 |       |
| to_customer  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                                 |       |
| published_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL                                 |       |
| expired_at   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL                                 |       |
| title        | varchar(512) | NO   |     | NULL                                 |       |
| content      | text         | YES  |     | NULL                                 |       |
| created_at   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL                                 |       |
| created_by   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL                                 |       |
| updated_at   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL                                 |       |
| updated_by   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL                                 |       |
| deleted_at   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL                                 |       |
| deleted_by   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL                                 |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+--------------------------------------+-------+
```

And I create an index like this :

```
+---------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name          | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| announcements |          0 | PRIMARY           |            1 | id           | A         |       76184 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| announcements |          1 | idx_announcements |            1 | provider_id  | A         |           7 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| announcements |          1 | idx_announcements |            2 | deleted_at   | A         |           7 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| announcements |          1 | idx_announcements |            3 | published_at | A         |           7 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| announcements |          1 | idx_announcements |            4 | to_provider  | A         |           7 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| announcements |          1 | idx_announcements |            5 | to_customer  | A         |           7 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| announcements |          1 | idx_announcements |            6 | expired_at   | A         |           7 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| announcements |          1 | idx_announcements |            7 | updated_at   | A         |           7 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

When I run

```
MariaDB [table_name]> EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `announcements` `t` WHERE (((`t`.provider_id = "3c5e63df-cb9b-f5a8-4eaf-7ed0061b797d") OR (provider_id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")) AND (`t`.deleted_at IS NULL))AND(((published_at <= "2015-07-17 14:54:36") AND ( to_provider IN (1))) AND (to_customer IN (0, 1)));
+------+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys     | key               | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t     | range | idx_announcements | idx_announcements | 64      | NULL | 38093 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
```

See, I can use the index,  but when I run

```
MariaDB [table_name]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `announcements` `t` WHERE (((`t`.provider_id = "3c5e63df-cb9b-f5a8-4eaf-7ed0061b797d") OR (provider_id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")) AND (`t`.deleted_at IS NULL))AND(((published_at <= "2015-07-17 14:54:36") AND ( to_provider IN (1))) AND (to_customer IN (0, 1)));
+------+-------------+-------+------+-------------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys     | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+-------------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t     | ALL  | idx_announcements | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 76184 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+------+-------------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
```

See, the key is null! I really don't get it. use the same where, but "select *" can not use the index.

Any one could tell me ?

Oh, and I got a SQL like this

```
SELECT * FROM `announcements` `t` 
WHERE 
    (((`t`.provider_id = :provider_id) OR (provider_id=:ycp0)) AND (`t`.deleted_at IS NULL)) 
    AND (published_at<="2015-07-17 16:58:57" AND (to_provider IN(1) AND to_customer IN (0,1)) 
    AND expired_at>="2015-07-17 16:58:57" 
    AND (updated_at > "2015-07-10 16:58:57" || published_at > "2015-07-10 16:58:57" )) 
ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 10
```

How to create index for this query ? I got a problem on "OR" thing ~~~

Comment: In order to retrieve all data, you need to retrieve all data. In order to count the number of rows, you only need to detect the presence of each row - you don't need to retrieve all of the data from those rows

Comment: Thank you, but how to create an index for this table, if I have a SQL like below, I tried, but stuck at the OR thing... : SELECT * FROM `announcements` `t` 
WHERE 
    (((`t`.provider_id = :provider_id) OR (provider_id=:ycp0)) AND (`t`.deleted_at IS NULL)) 
    AND (published_at<="2015-07-17 16:58:57" AND (to_provider IN(1) AND to_customer IN (0,1)) 
    AND expired_at>="2015-07-17 16:58:57" 
    AND (updated_at > "2015-07-10 16:58:57" || published_at > "2015-07-10 16:58:57" )) 
ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: Add an index covering both the to_provider and the to_customer columns (ie, one index covering both columns), possibly also covering either expired_at or published_at. MySQL will only take any notice of an index if it excludes a reasonable number of records, and I suspect that none of the indexes on their own you have currently set up reduce the number of records found by a sufficient amount. MySQL will only take any notice of one index on an instance of a table in a select.

Comment: By the way, most of the columns on your current index are probably of little use for searching as the id is unique. If you have the id then it can use that index but all the other columns would be irrelevant. If you do not have the id to search for then the whole index will be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way round the issue of MySQL only using a single index on any instance of a table in a select is to split the select into 2 and union them together.

For example with your select, if both `updated_at` and `published_at` would be useful indexes then you could allow MySQL to use them both as follows:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM announcements t 
WHERE t.provider_id IN ( :provider_id, :ycp0)
AND t.deleted_at IS NULL
AND published_at<="2015-07-17 16:58:57" 
AND to_provider IN(1) 
AND to_customer IN (0,1) 
AND expired_at>="2015-07-17 16:58:57" 
AND updated_at > "2015-07-10 16:58:57" 
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM announcements t 
WHERE t.provider_id IN ( :provider_id, :ycp0)
AND t.deleted_at IS NULL
AND published_at<="2015-07-17 16:58:57" 
AND to_provider IN(1) 
AND to_customer IN (0,1) 
AND expired_at>="2015-07-17 16:58:57" 
AND published_at > "2015-07-10 16:58:57" 
ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: thank you, but I do not need my old index any more, so I need a new index which could work on belowest sql.

Comment: Add an index on to_provider, to_customer and published_at. And add another index on to_provider, to_customer and updated_at. The above SQL would probably then use these indexes.